# Не могу добавить sonar server authentication token в jenkins

Tags: javascript, jenkins, непрерывная-интеграция, devops, sonarqube

При настройке SonarQube scanner plugin в jenkins столкнулся с проблемой добавления server authentication token. При нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит + она съехала.
Возможно кто сталкивался с данной проблемой. Устанавливал плагин без перезапуска jenkins.

[image: Bad add field]

Так же обратил внимание на эту ошибку в консоли:[image: Error in console]

Взглянув на код страницы обратил внимание на этот селект:[image: Bad select]

Возможно проблема именно в нем.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего jenkins не подтянул классы плагина из за того что не был перезапущен.
еще можно попробовать установить предыдущую версию плагина.
p.s. плагины не корректно работают без перезагрузки дженкинса.